# Display number of rows from db with pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have been trying to display number of rows from my db, but it displays 0 rows instead of 8 rows.

Here is my code:

```
    $db_hostname="127.0.0.1";
    $db_name="...";
    $db_username="...";
    $db_password=""; 

     try {
                $pdo=new PDO("mysql:host=$db_hostname;db=$db_name", $db_username, $db_password);


                    echo "Connection established";


            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo 'Cannot connect to database';
                exit;

            }
```

PHP code:

```
<?php include_once 'connection.inc.php';

try {

$sql='SELECT count(*) FROM images';

$result = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$result->execute();

$count= $result->rowCount();

echo $count;

$result->closeCursor();


catch (PDOException $e) {

 echo "Error in code".$e->getMessage(); 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `fetch*` functions to get query results:

```
$result = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$result->execute();
$row = $result->fetch();
print_r($row); // and see what key do you need in it
```

Answer (score 3):

Your resultset should contain one row. That row contains one column, which in turn contains the count of rows from your `images` table. So, instead of

```
$count = $result->rowCount();
```

which retrieves the count of rows in your resultset, you want

```
 $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
 $count = $row[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in your sql statement

```
$sth = $conn -> prepare("select count(*) as num_items from items");
$sth -> execute();
$result = $sth -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo $result['num_items']; //will output num of rows in the table if the table has records
```

Comment: `numrows` will give the number of rows the query returned. `count(*)` counts the number of rows and returns the count as one row. So this would only give back `1`. The value of this query is what the OP would need.

Comment: @Chris85 check my updated answer, I did include the full code.  tested and it works.